# c# Switch case not working

Tags: c#, switch-statement, typeconverter

I'm trying to check a value by using a `switch`:

```cs
private void btnInput1Rste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (sender == btnInput1Rste)
    {
        case "1": currentButtonPressedRste = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

It gives the error as follows:

> `can't convert type 'string' to 'bool'`

However, when i try to convert it to a boolean it says:

> `a constant value is expected`.

How do I fix it?

When it works it's supposed to check 3 values. (not with just this `switch`)

Comment: there are some really good online tutorials in the area of `C# Basics Tutorial` I would suggest that you start doing some remedial reading

Comment: What is supposed to happen when someone clicks your `btnInput1Rste` button? I'm almost 100% certain that the `switch` should be part of the logic of the event, not to determine if the `sender` is your button. I mean, do you really have this event hooked up to anything other than your `btnInput1Rste` `Click` event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sender == btnInput1Rste` is a boolean expression; the result is either `true` or `false`. Frankly, you probably just want an `if`/`else` here. You probably *can* do a `switch` with `case true:` but...

Comment: I must use a switch for the school assignment, otherwise it'd already work with an if/else. But the case true: works! :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Your switch is formatted oddly as well I think you want to see if `btnInput1Rste` was equal to the sender? And you don't have default case either.

```
 switch (sender)
    {
        case btnInput1Rste: 
             //This button was the sender
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue. Whatever type is in the parentheses of the switch statement must match the types of the cases. Here, you have a boolean value in the parentheses. Your case is checking for a string type. Bools and strings cannot be implicitly converted to one another, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 using switch, where we assume that your btnInput1Rste is a const string such:

```
    //..
    public const string btnInput1Rste= "some_value";

    ///...then this should work:
    switch (sender)
        {
            case btnInput1Rste:
                //enter code here
                break;
        }
```

Option 2 where the btnInput1Rste does not have to be constant string:

```
if(sender == btnInput1Rste){
      //enter code here
}
```

Comment: `sender` is an object, you can't `switch` on it. The `if` statement would work, but the OP said they need to use a `switch`

Comment: True, i did not paid attention on the method, rather to the switch statement.